# Batch Rest API call

Tags: java, rest, batch-processing

Is it possible to execute a batch REST API call in Java? I have multiple REST get API URLs and need to get all the details from all the response that I will get from these REST API call. It is taking too much time when I place them in a loop and call after each loop. Another approach that I have thought of using is to place each request in threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Multi-threading in JAVA to send multiple simultaneously!

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek. That is exactly how I did it.